# Steady periodic solution to $x''+2x'+4x=9\sin(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the steady periodic solution to the differential equation
$x''+2x'+4x=9\sin(t)$

in the form
$x_{sp}(t)=C\cos(\omega t−\alpha)$, with $C > 0$ and $0\le\alpha<2\pi$.

I don't know how to begin. First of all, what is a steady periodic solution? And how would I begin solving this problem?

Comment: It's a constant-coefficient nonhomogeneous equation. That means you need to find the solution to the homogeneous version of the equation, find one solution to the original equation, and then add them together. The steady state solution will consist of the terms that do not converge to $0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: A good start is solving the ODE (you could even start with the homogeneous).

Comment: So, I first solve the ODE using the characteristic equation and then using Euler's formula, then I use method of undetermined coefficients. I know that the solution is in the form of the ODE solution so I have to multiply by t right?

Answer (score 1):

To a differential equation you have two types of solutions to consider: homogeneous and inhomogeneous solutions.
The first is the solution to the equation
$$x''+2x'+4x=0$$
Taking the tried and true approach of method of characteristics then assuming that $x~e^{rt}$ we have:
$$r^2+2r+4=0 \rightarrow (r-r_-)(r-r+)=0 \rightarrow r=r_{\pm}$$
$$r_{\pm}=\frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4-16}}{2}= -1\pm i \sqrt{3}$$ 
We see that the homogeneous solution then has the form of decaying periodic functions:
$$x_{homogeneous}= Ae^{(-1+ i \sqrt{3})t}+ Be^{(-1- i \sqrt{3})t}=(Ae^{i \sqrt{3}t}+ Be^{- i \sqrt{3}t})e^{-t}$$
Again, these are periodic since we have $e^{i\omega t}$, but they are not steady state solutions as they decay proportional to $e^{-t}$.

The other part of the solution to this equation is then the solution that satisfies the original equation:
$$D[x_{inhomogeneous}]= f(t)$$

Upon inspection you can say that this solution must take the form of $Acos(\omega t) + Bsin(\omega t)$. That is because the RHS, f(t), is of the form $sin(\omega t)$.  You then need to plug in your expected solution and equate terms in order to determine an appropriate A and B. Once you do this you can then use trig identities to re-write these in terms of c, $\omega$, and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the real parts of the roots of the characteristic equation is $-1$, which is negative, as $t \to \infty$, the homogenious solution will vanish. We only have the particular solution in our hands.

$$\eqalign{x_p(t) &= A\sin(t) + B\cos(t)\cr
x_p'(t) &= A\cos(t) - B\sin(t)\cr
x_p''(t) &= -A\sin(t) - B\cos(t)\cr}$$

Then the equation will be

$$(-A - 2B + 4A)\sin(t) + (-B + 2A + 4B)\cos(t) = 9\sin(t)$$

$$\eqalign{3A - 2B &= 1\cr
2A + 3B &= 0\cr}$$

$$A = 3/13, B = -2/13$$

Therefore steady state solution is $\displaystyle x_p(t) = \frac{3}{13}\,\sin(t) - \frac{2}{13}\,\cos(t)$

Comment: I think $A=-\frac{18}{13},~~~~B=\frac{27}{13}$. Is it not ? @crbah

Answer (score 0):

> The **steady periodic solution** is the particular solution of a differential equation with damping.

**Solution:** Given differential equation is$$x''+2x'+4x=9\sin t \tag1$$
First, the form of the complementary solution must be determined in order to make sure that the particular solution does not have duplicate terms.

Roots of the trial solution is $$r=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4-16}}{2}=-1\pm i\sqrt3$$
The general form of the complementary solution  (or transient solution) is $$x_{c}=e^{-t}\left(a~\cos(\sqrt 3~t)+b~\sin(\sqrt 3~t)\right)$$where $~a,~b~$ are constants.

Let us assumed that the **particular solution**, or **steady periodic solution** is of the form $$x_{sp} =A \cos t + B \sin t$$
Here our assumption is fine as no terms are repeated in the complementary solution. The
general form of the particular solution is now substituted into the differential equation  $(1)$ to determine the constants $~A~$ and $~B~$.

We have $$(-A\cos t -B\sin t)+2(-A\sin t+B\cos t)+4(A \cos t + B \sin t)=9\sin t$$
$$\implies (3A+2B)\cos t+(-2A+3B)\sin t=9\sin t$$
Comparing we have $$A=-\frac{18}{13},~~~~B=\frac{27}{13}$$ 
So the steady periodic solution is $$x_{sp}=-\frac{18}{13}\cos t+\frac{27}{13}\sin t$$
This particular solution can be converted into the form $$x_{sp}(t)=C\cos(\omega t−\alpha)$$where $\quad C=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\frac{9}{\sqrt{13}},~~\alpha=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)=-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=-0.982793723~ rad,~~ \omega= 1$

The value of $~\alpha~$ is in the $~4^{th}~$ quadrant. Since $~B~$ is
positive and $~A~$ is negative, $~α~$ must be in the $~3^{rd}~$ quadrant. So $~α = π -0.982793723 = 2.15879893059 ~$.

So the steady periodic solution is $$x_{sp}(t)=\left(\frac{9}{\sqrt{13}}\right)\cos(t−2.15879893059)$$

---

The general solution is $$x(t)=e^{-t}\left(a~\cos(\sqrt 3~t)+b~\sin(\sqrt 3~t)\right)+\frac{1}{13}(-18 \cos t + 27 \sin t)$$